# Get new access_token without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-visualization, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

(Using Google Analytics Embed API) Is it possible to request a new access_token without reloading the page.

The current code is:

```
$.getScript('https://www.google.com/jsapi', function(){
        // Load the embed API library
        (function(w, d, s, g, js, fs) {
            g = w.gapi || (w.gapi = {});
            g.analytics = {
                q: [],
                ready: function(f) {
                    this.q.push(f);
                }
            };
            js = d.createElement(s);
            fs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            js.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
            fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fs);
            js.onload = function() {
                g.load('analytics');
            };
        }(window, document, 'script'));

        gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

            gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
                container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
                clientid: 'xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
            });

            callback();

        });
    });
```

Which makes it possible to get the current access_token using `gapi.analytics.auth.getAuthResponse().access_token`

The problem is that after one hour without no reload the token is no longer valid and will return empty queries. Is it possible to get a new token without reloading the page?

The access_token is used in a single page application.

Comment: As far as I know you don't get a refresh token back from Js library so you have no way to refresh it.  You should prompt the user to login again.   This might help https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#authorizing-and-making-authorized-requests

Comment: But when a user refreshes the page, they don't have to log in and automatically get a new token.

Comment: As far as I can tell the library should be refreshing it for you.  I cant find any method to enable you to refresh this yourself.

Comment: So for a single page application, the only solution would be to force reload the page every 1 hour? If I want to use the embed api

Comment: Yes that's the only way I have heard of doing it before.   I haven't actually tried I am assuming this is some kind of static dashboard you have displayed somewhere.